# Xamarin Converter not working on IsEnabled Property

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, converters

I am using a converter code below

```
namespace someAssembly.Converters
{
    public class ValidateTextLengthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (int)value != 0;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool)value ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Xaml

Namespace:

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:someNamepsace.someAssembly.Converters;assembly=someAssembly"
```

Resources:

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
         <converter:ValidateTextLengthConverter x:Key="validateLength" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
```

Usage: (edit I added the textbox being refered by converter)

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<Label Text="Name:" />
<Entry x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>

<Button x:Name="btnSave" Text="Save" 
Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
BackgroundColor="{x:Static local:ColorResources.ButtonColorTransparent}" 
IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference txtName},
Path=Text.Length,
Converter={StaticResource validateLength}}"  />
```

My main purpose is to disable a button when a textbox length is still zero. It seems that Converter or IsEnabled is not firing. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: What button does? Where is it action? I suggest to bind command to button and write its CanExecute to check length of entry text. This way you could have logic in view model and you won't need to have converter to disable button

Comment: I omitted the button function but it is bound to a Command I am using a ViewModelContext rather than the forms code behind via Clicked event.

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean now can you give me a snippets for CanExecute? I am using Prism

Comment: Something like:

        private bool CanExecuteMyCommand()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                return false
            return true;
        }

and in setter of name add "MyCommand?.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();"

Answer (score 1):

Oh well, There's nothing wrong with the code. The error is in my Bindable property where the value needs to be initialized.

From:

```
private string _Name; //<-- not initialized, Null
public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _Name, value); }
}
```

To:

```
private string _Name = string.Empty; //<-- needs to be empty or "" string
public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _Name, value); }
}
```

But inspite of a working converter, I opted to use a DelegateCommand so I can check for the length of more than one properties.

```
public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }

SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(SaveItem, canExecute)
        .ObservesProperty(() => this.Name)
        .ObservesProperty(() => this.Title)
        .ObservesProperty(() => this.Description);




public bool canExecute()
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name) &&    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Title) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Description);
}


private async void SaveItem()
    {
       //Put your saving logic here.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bind to Text property which is bindable, instead of its length.
Then you should modify the converter to handle string instead of int.

Comment: Thanks. The logic is to test the length of the other control's text property then decide to enable or disable the button based on data entry.